# ajax abort is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to abort previous ajax request while starting new one i am using this code but its not working

```
<?php $urlToFetchPrice = 'getShippingAmount.php'; ?>
var $wk_jq = jQuery.noConflict();
$wk_jq('#weight').on('input', function() {
    var $this = $wk_jq(this);
    var $element = $wk_jq(this.element);
    var previous_request;
    if (previous_request) {
        previous_request.abort();
    }
    previous_request = $wk_jq.ajax({
        url: "<?=$urlToFetchPrice?>",
        data: {
            weight: $this.val(),
            country: 'BH'
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        format
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
});
```

It's not showing any error in console but not aborting previous request. I have also tried this:

```
beforeSend: function() {
        if (previous_request != null) {
            previous_request.abort();
        }
```

This also not working.

Comment: Be aware, it will abort it client side but not server side. You would have better to debounce your input event a little to avoid calling a new request on each input, although you (try to) abort any previous one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `var previous_request;` to outside of your `.on` function. You defined it wrong place, so it will be empty always.

You can `console.log` / debug that too, to check does it has value.

```
var previous_request;
$wk_jq('#weight').on('input', function() {
   //.....
});
```